# Objects to support the front page of my Django powered web site?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am building my first django website and I am having trouble understanding what objects are needed to support the front page of the website.

The front page has a structure very much like the front page of [12 Factor App](http://12factor.net/) and I am wondering what django objects; models, views etc. do I need to achieve this.

The page will contain several headings with text that will change infrequently. Below this text will be a list of links to other parts of the site. All the content will be added via the Admin app.

At the moment I have the following model:

```
class FrontPage(models.Model):
    introduction = models.CharField(max_length = 4000)
    updates = models.CharField(max_length = 4000)
```

My view (simplified) looks like this:

```
def indexpage(request):
    front_page = get_object_or_404(FrontPage, pk=1)
    collection_list = CarCollection.objects.orderby('the_year')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'collection': collection_list, 'frontpage': front_page})
```

Which I pass to my template and my page is displayed as expected, I see the text and the links.

However I am sure there must be a more "django" type way to develop this type of page so any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

In case of need I am using Django 1.6

Answer (score 2):

If it is just text base then you probably do not need anything. You could just install django-cms and let it handle the content.

The links below the introduction at the link you posted seem to be just content pages and that is exactly what django-cms provides. You do not need to add any models of your own most likely.